# Collect active tab HTML content in Crossrider

Tags: javascript, jquery, crossrider

I'm building a browser extension which needs to collect all the HTML on a given page before passing it to background.js

extension.js code looks like this (partial code obviously):

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
     var html = $('html').html();

...
```

It works perfectly on very simple test pages, however on some pages it's not collecting the correct HTML, it's hard to work out exactly what it's doing but I think it's collecting the contents of iFrames (and somehow social share buttons?).

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the code snippet provided should do the trick. I suspect the results you are seeing is because you have enabled the **Run in Iframes** feature on the **General Settings** page and hence grabbing iframe information as well. If this is not the case, if you provide the *extension id* I can take a look and try and assist you further.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Brilliant, that was an easy fix! I'd turned that on ages ago and forgotten...

Thank you.